# Taskbar Toolbar (DeskBand) in VB.NET for Win7 x64

Tags: vb.net, 64-bit, toolbar, taskbar, deskband

I want create a **DeskBand** application for **Windows 7 64bit** in **VB2013**.
I found two helpful sites:

1. [Band Object Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776819%28VS.85%29.aspx#band_object_basics)
2. [Extending Explorer with Band Objects Using .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2219/Extending-Explorer-with-Band-Objects-using-NET-and)

My problem is, if I want activate my toolbar, drop the popup window that say this: "**** toolbar isn't compatible with this version of Windows."

I write this on Win x64 with VB.NET Target Platform\CPU: x64

My VB.NET project files:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=01064589043620484857

**What could be the problem?**

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Codeproject.com projects chronically lack the "only works on my machine" disclaimer.  Do not target .NET 2.0, very important to use 4.0 today so you can survive the CLR version injection problem.  And use the correct version of regasm.exe, the 4.0 64-bit version.

Comment: I created a new project with .NET 4.0 x64 but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

You DeskBand must implement [IDeskBand2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. And IDeskBand2.CanRenderComposited method must set CanRenderComposited to TRUE.

Comment: The situation remained unchanged.